# Do I need to watch Agents of SHIELD before watching Agent Carter or Daredevil?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield, agent-carter, daredevil-tv

I was just wondering if I need to watch the Marvel Cinematic Universe television shows in order of airing. I haven't watched *Agents of SHIELD* - would I miss out on anything if I went ahead and watched *Agent Carter* and *Daredevil*?

Do characters/plotlines cross over? Or do they work fine on their own?

Please DO NOT post any spoilers. If you must, format them in spoiler blocks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are some small, Easter egg type links between *Agents of SHIELD*, *Agent Carter* and *Daredevil* - but in general, they follow seperate characters in different areas of the world, and even different time periods.

Unless you REALLY need to know how every aspect of the Marvel Cinematic Universe is linked, then you won't be missing out on anything by watching *Agent Carter* or *Daredevil* without first seeing *Agents of SHIELD*.

That being said, you may wish to make sure that you have seen at least *Captain America: The First Avenger* before watching *Agent Carter*, as the two are quite firmly linked.

Comment: Also, I recommend watching "The Avengers" before starting on "Agents of SHIELD", as it explains a great deal about a main character's situation.  Similarly, the events of "Captain America: Winter Soldier" are integral to the later seasons of "Agents of SHIELD".

Comment: @Liesmith That said, any references to the *other* MCU movies always feel a bit forced... I remember someone saying something along the lines of "Horrible what happened in Sokovia... anyway, now for something completely different..."

Answer (score 5):

The shows are setup to be independent from the movies and each other. There are references and easter eggs that enrich each other, but nothing essential.

If you want the most out of it, watch the shows in the order they were released: [image: Marvel movies and shows in order.]

Source: https://www.cnet.com/how-to/marvel-cinematic-universe-timeline-avengers/